# Save screenshot even when path doesn't exists?

Tags: puppeteer

```
await page.screenshot({path: `results/screenshots/${projectname}/${date}/SiteAdded.png`});
```

When the above line of code is executed, it fails with error as below

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'results/screenshots/...../SiteAdded.png'
```

That's true because the path is not yet present on the system. Is there anyway (like a flag) I can use to tell puppeteer to create the nested folders first and then save the file?

My workaround is to created the folders first using other apis and then pass the path to page.screenshot, but I am wondering if there is any direct way.

**Update**

Filed a tracking issue in the Github Project as suggested in comments.

Here is the tracker: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6093 if anyone interested.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such Chromium/puppeteer flag nor `page.screenshot` option available that would do this. The only way is to use Node's  "`fs`" to create the directory before the screenshot is saved by puppeteer.

[fs.mkdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options) would do the job:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

[...] 

const path = `results/screenshots/${projectname}/${date}`;

fs.mkdirSync(path);
await page.screenshot({ path: `${path}/SiteAdded.png` });
```

Comment: Thanks! fs is what I am using as well, but it would be cool if Puppeteer would do it for us.

Comment: I just checked and [playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) behaves the same (I suppose they just copied `page.screenshot` from puppeteer). I think using "fs" is okey, it is not an extra dependency or something, but if the lack of directory creation in path option really disturbs you feel free to raise a feature request to puppeteer team on GitHub: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/new

Comment: Thanks, thats where I first checked but some how came back to stackoverflow. Will file a feature request today

Comment: Filed an issue in github. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being able to reply in comments (newbie here), but in addition to the suggestion of @theDavidBarton, you could check if the directory exists beforehand or use try/catch.
 example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

[...] 
const path = `results/screenshots/${projectname}/${date}`;

try {
     await page.screenshot({ path: `${path}/SiteAdded.png` });
} catch(err) {
     fs.mkdirSync(path);
     await page.screenshot({ path: `${path}/SiteAdded.png` });
}
```

Comment: There was a typo in my original answer, could you correct the fs modul name to  `fs.mkdirSync(path);` as camelcase in your solution as well?

Comment: sure, here you go